# facebook login null pointer exception android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

I searched a lot through stackoverflow but I couldn't find an answer that resolves my issue. Hence I am posting this.

I have a sample Android App in which I'm trying to use facebook Login. Here are the steps that I followed:

Environment: Android studio
Android SDK version : 22
Facebook SDK : 4.0

Followed the steps to install FB APK on the emulator, generated the Developer hash key and updated it in app-> settings.
My android manifest has these code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

In my activity_main.xml layout file, I have this piece of code

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fblogin_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

And finally in my main Activity I have this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LoginButton loginButton;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fblogin_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb on cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb Login Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Inside Fb login","on Activiry result");
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception as shown below

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity componentInfo{PROJECT.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(com.facebook.CallbackManager, com.facebook.FacebookCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you're getting a `NullPointerException` because you're calling `findViewById()` before you call `setContentView()`, so `loginButton` is null when you call `loginButton.registerCallback()`.

Just move the call to `setContentView()` to the top:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Moved up here to resolve NPE

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fblogin_button);
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb on cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fb Login Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: placing FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); before 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); did the trick. Thanks for your help @Daniel

Answer (score 9):

The crash seems to be related to the applicationId we are setting in the `AndoridMenifest.xml` file. As i figured out that when facebook sdk is tying to create the `LoginFramment` then ApplicationId is comming as `null`.Here is onCreate method of `com.facebook.login.LoginFragment` class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            this.loginClient = (LoginClient)savedInstanceState.getParcelable("loginClient");
            this.loginClient.setFragment(this);
        } else {
            this.loginClient = new LoginClient(this);
        }

        this.loginClient.setOnCompletedListener(new OnCompletedListener() {
            public void onCompleted(Result outcome) {
                LoginFragment.this.onLoginClientCompleted(outcome);
            }
        });
        FragmentActivity activity = this.getActivity();
        if(activity != null) {
            this.initializeCallingPackage(activity);
            if(activity.getIntent() != null) {
                //the applicationId in this.request object is null 
                this.request = (Request)activity.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("request");

            }

        }
    }
```

As pointed out by the varoius post the applicationId is coming null because the string resource `app_id` is not being parsed correctly by android.
https://github.com/jamesward/AndroidStringBug

I solved this probelm by setting the applicationId manually after initializing the facebook sdk as given below in `onCreate` method.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

Comment: why the metadata string is not working? I got the same issue...did what you suggested.

Comment: I have the same issue and now I dont know how to solve it with the latest SDK because it deprecates sdkInitiliaze method and because of that it doesnt allow me to set ApplicationId witihin onCreate? any suggestion?

Comment: Just prefix the meta-data value with fb, see source code: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/sdk-version-4.8.0/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L598

Answer (score 0):

as anj indicated problem is usually with the ApplicationId was not read. in my case, Problem was with the namespace. make sure that your namespace of the class is the root namespace. So my app is an xamarin android app and i was using namespace as below but my Android App's namespace is myApp.Droid, this way ApplicaitonId is not read from strings.xml changing to myApp.Droid fixed my problem. I hope that it helps anyone else having similar issue

```
[assembly: MetaData("com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId", Value = "@string/app_id")]
namespace myApp.Droid.Renderer
```