# Null Pointer exception handling Facebook login for android - com.facebook.FacebookCallback

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement Facebook login in the app I am developing on. But I keep getting a NullPointerException, and I am not quite sure why.

The class with the implementation:

```
public class FacebookLogInActivity extends Activity {
private TextView info;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.com_facebook_activity_layout);

    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            info.setText(getString(R.string.facebook_login_successful,
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(),
                    loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            info.setText(R.string.facebook_login_cancel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            info.setText(R.string.facebook_login_fail);
        }
    });
}
```

The relevant part of the error I get when compiling:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fapptory_inc.rideshare/fapptory_inc.rideshare.FacebookLogInActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.registerCallback(com.facebook.CallbackManager, com.facebook.FacebookCallback)' on a null object reference
```

Other stuff that might be of importance: [activity_facebook_log_in.xml](http://pastebin.com/Pq9chVGc), [AndroidManifest.xml](http://pastebin.com/9SKStyW8), [build.gradle](http://pastebin.com/uABDNM0N)

I've read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454586/facebook-login-null-pointer-exception-android) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298996/facebook-android-sdk-v4-0-0-sharedialog-nullpointerexception-issue) questions already asked, and as far I can see, I have fixed my similar problems. Where do I go now?

Comment: Hey, you are using setcontentView(com_facebook_activity_layout) and then when yoy post your xml its name is  activity_facebook_log_in.xml

Comment: You are right. Completely missed that. Thank you very much, and thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting other Layout to your activity, not the one that you created for this activity, you should set the one correctly:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook_log_in);
```